# How do I send an HTTP request in C# without using System.Net classes?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, unity-game-engine

Is there a way in C#, perhaps using an external library of some kind, to perform HTTP web requests without using the built-in .NET classes (HttpRequest, WebRequest, WebClient...) ?

I ask because I'm working on a game in the [Unity3D](http://www.unity3D.com) engine, which allows you to use *most* of .NET through Mono. However, the System.Net namespace isn't supported in its web player. I need to do an HTTP request (polling a php file) and wait (sleep) until I've gotten a response. Unity3D provides its own WWW class which can do web requests, but it forces you to use an asynchronous callback function - which I know how to use but is extremely inconvenient in the context of our code.

So I'm looking for any alternative to the System.Net classes which can do this for me. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There might be a problem (_in the future_): "In the future the FCL build will be replaced by the newer Indy.Sockets CLR project."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might want to try [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org/index.en.aspx).

Comment: -1: Indy is built on top of System.Net

Comment: Indy solved it, thanks kprobst! =)

Lasse, there apparently are two versions of Indy. One is built on top of .NET and one isn't. The latter one solved my problem nicely.

Comment: There's a version that does not depend on System.Net.